# How to filter multiple JSON data using vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, search, filter, vuejs2

I would like to create a simple web apps that can display all json data
and user can filter it?

here it my code
I am using Vue 2

index.html

```
<div id="app">    
    <input type="input" id="txt-search" v-model="mySearch">
   <select>
      <option :value="post.id" v-for="post in searchBook"
              >{{post.id}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

script.js

```
var json_data = 'jsonfile.json'
var app = new Vue({

  el: '#app',
  data: {  
    posts: null,
    mySearch:''  
  },

  created: function () {
    this.fetchData()
  },

  methods: {
    fetchData: function () {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
      var self = this
      xhr.open('GET', json_data)
      xhr.onload = function () {
        self.posts = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
      }
      xhr.send()
    }
  },
computed: {
    searchBook() {
        return this.mySearch ? this.posts.filter(post => {
            return post.title.includes(this.mySearch);
          })
        : this.posts;
    }
}
})
```

It only filter title data

```
post.title.includes(this.mySearch)
```

Is it posible to filter all json data like

```
post.*.includes(this.mySearch)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function filterArray(arr, keyword) {
  if (!keyword) return arr;
  return arr.filter(obj =>
    Object.values(obj)
      .some(value => typeof value === 'string' && value.includes(keyword))
  );
}
```

Usage:

```
computed: {
    searchBook() {
        return filterArray(this.posts, this.mySearch);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is but is a little complicated. First, you must extract all the values from the object and filter every record to check if it contains the searched phrase.

Example:

```js
const posts = [
  {title: 'title1', author:'author1', comment: 'comment1'},
  {title: 'foo', author:'author2', comment: 'comment2'},
  {title: 'title3', author:'bar', comment: 'comment3'},
]

const serchedPhrase = 'author';

const filteredData = posts.filter((e) => {
  const values = Object.keys(e).map(val => e[val]);
  const filteredValues = values.filter((el) => el.includes(serchedPhrase));
  return filteredValues.length > 0;
});

console.log(filteredData);
```